# Error: clarabel.so is linked against unknown library 'libgcc_s.so.1'. when building wheel file

Tags: python, linux, python-wheel, chaquopy, libgcc

I am using Chaquopy to build whl file following [this page](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/tree/master/server/pypi) for clarabel python library on Linux. I have tried other library and it works. However for clarabel, it gives error.

> build-wheel: Error: /home/yolopoi/chaquopy/server/pypi/packages/clarabel/build/0.6.0/cp38-cp38-android_21_arm64_v8a/fix_wheel/clarabel/clarabel.so is linked against unknown library 'libgcc_s.so.1'.

meta.yaml

```
package:
  name: clarabel
  version: "0.6.0"
```

I have checked that `./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1`, `./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1` exist. I tried to copy it to /lib that `./lib/libgcc_s.so.1` but it does not work. How can I fix it?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a good forum for debugging these kinds of issues. Please create an issue on the [Chaquopy Github page](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy), and include the full build log.